# Accessing a Model from js.erb file when precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, precompile

I have a Rails 3 app where I am trying to populate a javascript variable with every Nation in my database (less than 300 nations) as a JSON object.  This is the relevant line in my `nations.js.erb` file:

```
_this.nations = <%= Nation.all.to_json :only => [:id], :methods => :text %>;
```

When I call my js file in a browser, `/assets/users.js` which does a require of the nations file, the `_this.nations` variable is populated perfectly. When I try to do a precompile I get the following:

```
$> rake assets:precompile
$> rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Nation (in nations.js.erb)
```

So my question is this: is it possible to reference the `Nation` model, or any model, from within the `js.erb` file for precompiling?  I also tried using my `NationsHelper` but my error just changed to uninitialized constant NationsHelper.

I'm fairly new to RoR so if relevant information is needed that I haven't provided, please just ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` set to `false` somewhere then try enabling it

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

Comment: This surprisingly does *not* effect Heroku's intialize_on_precompile problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the call in the controller

controller

```
@nations = Nation.all
```

nations.js.erb

```
_this.nations = <%= @nations.all.to_json :only => [:id], :methods => :text %>;
```